# Backbone Fetch not triggering Change event when Collection receives new data

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, fetch

Below I have a Collection that fetches a list of messages from a RESTful API. (I chose a Collection because it will eventually store the parsed data.)

My View is set to watch for changes in the Collection (i.e. when a new message is received). However, the Collection does not appear to trigger a change or set event when the new data is stored. I have logged the Collection before and after to confirm that its results attribute has changed.

A few questions:

1. Why does a 'change' event fail to occur when unique data is received?
2. I anticipate running a setInterval on my fetchMessages function to continually check for updated data from the server. Is there a better way to check for updates in Backbone?

Thanks for your help!

**Collection**

```
var AllMessages = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  model: Message,
  url: 'http://arestfulapi.com',

  fetchMessages: function(){
    var that = this;
    this.fetch({
      data: {
        'order': '-createdAt',
        'limit': 10
      },
      success: function(model, data){
        // we want the array in data.results
        that.set(data.results) // this should trigger a change event ?
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**View**

```
var MessageViewer = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function(){
    this.collection.on('change',this.log,this); // does not get called from above
  },

  log: function(e){
    console.log('triggered');
  }

});
```

**Instantiation**

```
var allMessages = new AllMessages();
var messageViewer = new MessageViewer({collection:allMessages});
```

Comment: You don't have a model, you have a collection, that's a bit different. When you're talking about updating attributes, aren't you refering to models being added to that Collection? Also, don't use `reset` like that. Instead, use the flag `{reset: true}` when fetching. Here you're basically telling Backbone to do a smart update on your collection and then to reset it right afterwards. Now, if you use the reset flag, you'll also be able to listen to the `reset` event. But seeing the kind of code you have, I'm not sure you really want to reset your collection...

Comment: I should have made note that the API is RESTful and is responding with a full list of objects, including those that I already have. Is it possible for Backbone to examine this list for differences between my Collection and the (potentially) updated list?

Comment: Yes it is, and is the default behavior (starting Backbone 1.0 if I'm not mistaken). Backbone will simply check the ids to do so. To quote the doc: *When the model data returns from the server, it uses set to (intelligently) merge the fetched models*.

Comment: How would I rewrite this code so that Backbone finds these changes and triggers the 'change' event?

Comment: are you sure it fires a 'set' event? Try listening to the 'change' event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved:

According to the [Backbone.js Catalog of Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog):

- "add" triggers when a model is added to a collection.
- "change" triggers when a model's attributes have changed.

Because this collection is having models added to an existing attribute ('models'), rather than having attributes altered, **this triggers an 'add' event**. That the initial 'models' attribute holds an empty array is not relevant here.